# Can someone point me in the right direction about isothermal compression process

Tags: humidity

I am reading book about compressors and I have a question about isothermal process and water condensation.

Is it true that during actual compression process water vapor will condense? I was always under the assumption that water condenses after it passes through inter and after coolers.

Can someone please point me in the right direction what I should be reviewing to understand this better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal gas, isothermal compression requires contact with a cold source since for the temperature to be constant it is necessary to compensate the work that is introduced for compression with a heat output.

In the case of water vapor, under the curve of the pressure-volume diagram of phase change, water and steam coexist, here the isotherms are horizontal: (See figure)
[image]

- Isotherm: A horizontal transition from right to left assumes that the volume is reduced at constant temperature and without increasing the pressure because part of the steam becomes water. This is what happens in a condenser. (I have drawn a yellow line)
- If there is a compression afterwards, it is not isothermal, and there is also steam in it which becomes water, therefore there is also condensation. This is what happens in a pump. (I have drawn a red line)

I hope it can be of some help.